# How can I recursively change the owner of a directory to the user nobody in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to change the owner of a directory and all files and directories below it to the user `nobody`.

I have a `/parent_dir` with owner `root`. I want to change the owner to nobody (system user) recursively.

Answer (score 61):

Like this:

```
sudo chown -R nobody /parent_dir
```

Comment: This requires sudo, the answer below is better.

Answer (score 14):

You may change the owner of the directory recursively using the following command. `-R` stands for recursive.

```
chown -R ownername foldername
```

You can also change the owner and group of the directory recursively using the following command.

```
chown -R ownername:groupname foldername
```

For more details refer [this.](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by `chown` with `-R` option. `-R` is for recursive.

If `Demo` is the folder name and `apache` is the `user` and `group`, then run,

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache Demo
```

This will change the owner and group of every folder and files to `apache`.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `-R` command line parameter of chown.

```
chown -R nobody /parent_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to the other answers:

```
sudo find /parent_dir -exec chown nobody {} \;
```

if you only want to change files you could use `-type f` or `-type d` for directories. comes in handy, when you want to `chmod` stuff.

Comment: another thing you can do here is restrict it to only change files from one particular owner to another.  If only a few files are root owned that can save a lot of metadata writes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make this parameter no_root_squash on /etc/exports

- vi  /etc/exports
- no_root_squash
- wq

Good luck.